# Calculating standard error after a log-transform

Tags: r, statistics

Consider a random set of numbers that are normally distributed:

```
x <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=10)
```

We'd like to know the mean and the standard error on the mean so we do the following:

```
se <- function(x) { sd(x)/length(x) }
mean(x) # something near 10.0 units
se(x)   # something near 0.001 units
```

Great!

However, let's assume we don't necessarily know that our original distribution follows a normal distribution. We log-transform the data and perform the same standard error calculation.

```
z <- log(x, base=10)
mean(z) # something near 1 log units
se(z)   # something near 0.000043 log units
```

Cool, but now we need to back-transform to get our answer in units NOT log units.

```
10^mean(z) # something near 10.0 units
10^se(z)   # something near 1.00 units
```

My question: Why, for a normal distribution, does the standard error differ depending on whether it was calculated from the distribution itself or if it was transformed, calculated, and back-transformed? In this example, it is interesting that the difference is almost exactly 3 orders of magnitude. Note: the means came out the same regardless of the transformation.

EDIT #1: Ultimately, I am interested in calculating a mean and confidence intervals for non-normally distributed data, so if you can give some guidance on how to calculate 95% CI's on transformed data including how to back-transform to their native units, I would appreciate it!

END EDIT #1

EDIT #2: I tried using the quantile function to get the 95% confidence intervals:

```
quantile(x, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))     # around [8.3, 11.6]
10^quantile(z, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))  # around [8.3, 11.6]
```

So, that converged on the same answer, which is good. However, using this method doesn't provide the exact same interval using non-normal data with "small" sample sizes:

```
t <- rlnorm(10)
mean(t)                            # around 1.46 units
10^mean(log(t, base=10))           # around 0.92 units
quantile(t, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))                     # around [0.211, 4.79]
10^(quantile(log(t, base=10), probs = c(0.05, 0.95)))  # around [0.209, 4.28]
```

Which method would be considered "more correct". I assume one would pick the most conservative estimate?

As an example, would you report this result for the non-normal data (t) as having a mean of 0.92 units with a 95% confidence interval of [0.211, 4.79]?

END EDIT #2

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Simple approach for 95% CI on arbitrary distribution, use hist function and identify the 2.5% tails.  Iterate on the break points as needed.

Comment: Not a coding question. Read about the relationship of the normal and log-normal distributions and followup to CrossValidated.com

Comment: It seems it has been answered
Please take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123514/calculating-standard-error-after-a-log-transform